# Very Basic jQuery usage: using $(this) or var

Tags: jquery, tabs, this, var

This is my first usage of jQuery. I just want a quick solution for the following:

It is very simple; when div #a1.toolbotbut is clicked, div #a1p is shown. 
When #a2.toolbotbut is clicked, div #a2p is shown. 
When #b2.toolbotbut is clicked, div #b2p is shown, etc etc. 
So the indivdual jquery looks like this:

```
$('#a1.toolbotbut').click(function() {
  $('#a1p.overlay').fadeIn('slow');
  });
```

and

```
$('#a2.toolbotbut').click(function() {
  $('#a2p.overlay').fadeIn('slow');
  });
```

Could you tell me how to use $(this) or var to pick out the div id of the selected and insert that into $('...p.overlay') so I can use two lines of code for the whole function. Don't worry about hiding or marking active... just the basic technique I need here.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('.toolbotbut').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var overlayId = '#' + id + 'p.overlay';
  $(overlayId).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` variable refers to the object that calls the function() in the click event (i.e. `#a1.toolbotbut`). If you refer to `this` inside the function, you're actually referring to `#a1.toolbotbut`. If you wrap `this` in $() as `$(this)`, then you've made `#a1.toolbotbut` into a jQuery object.

jQuery objects have the `attr` method, which will return an attribute or property, so you can do something like:

```
var div_id = $(this).attr(); // returns "a1"
```

I hope I understood what you're asking and that this helps. Good luck.